# Find an integrable function that is not integrable for sufficiently close functions

Tags: integration, analysis

The problem is to find $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that

\begin{equation}
f\in L^1(0,1) \quad \text{ and} \quad X^{-\varepsilon}f \notin L^1(0,1)
\end{equation}
for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

Here $X$ denotes multiplication by $x$ so $(X^{-\varepsilon}f)(x) = x^{-\varepsilon}f(x)$.

It might be that such a function does not exist, but I have been incapable of showing this fact... Any thoughts?

Comment: Note that if $f$ is bounded, then $x^{-\epsilon}f(x) \in L^1$ for all $\epsilon\in (0,1).$ This means if you are to find such an $f$ it must be unbounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac 1 {x (\ln (x))^{2}}$ for $0<x<\frac 1 2 $ and $0$ for $\frac  1 2 \leq x <1$. Make the substitution $y=\ln x$ to see that this works.

Comment: Very elegant indeed!